# Troubles deploying my API to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing a very simple API in ASP.NET Core for testing purposes.

I have an endpoint at `https://localhost:5678/api/Values/addition/{a}/{b}` which just adds number A and B and stores the result in a database.

The database is stored on Azure. In local, the application is running well and connects to my Azure SQL Server database successfully. I have hardcoded the connection string to avoid any complexifications which can result in errors. I'll change it later.

I have also created a Release Pipeline on Azure. First, here is the `azure-pipelines.yml` :

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The release pipeline is triggered whenever a new push is detected on the `master` branch :

[image]

The job triggered is quite simple, it has a `Run On Agent` which triggers the deployment of my application to an `Azure App Service` like that :

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy To Development'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '{MY SUBSCRIPTION ID}'
    appType: webAppLinux
    WebAppName: '{MY APP SERVICE NAME}'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: '{MY RESOURCEGROUP NAME, SAME AS THE APP SERVICE}'
```

The build is successful, all jobs run successfully.

I can now navigate to my app service url `https://{MY APP SERVICE NAME}.azurewebsites.net` and get the welcome page of Azure :

[image]

I assume that at this point, I should be able to navigate to `https://{MY APP SERVICE NAME}.azurewebsites.net/api/Values/addition/{a}/{b}` and get a response from my API but instead of it, I get an error 404. The api endpoint just doesn't exist.

I've hardcoded everything to avoid system errors like non-acccessible external service, my log stream is also empty, and finally I've used kudu to verify that I have a correct `web.config` on my application. Everything is, I think, well  published.

What am I missing here ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I've modified my Pipeline as following :

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '{MY FEED}'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true
    modifyOutputPath: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

It modified my `wwwroot/` of the App Service, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: On your Web App management blade in the Azure Portal, go to the Diagnostic Logs menu item. Turn on Application Logging, Web server logging, detailed error messages, and failed request tracing, you will be able to go to the Diagnose and Solve Problems menu option and view Failed Request Tracing Logs. You will also be able to browse both the web server logs and application logs for the detailed error.

Comment: app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }
        );

```

Also, try adding these lines in the configuration section of the `startup.cs`

Comment: I've modified my Pipeline but it still doesn't work. I've created an edit on my first post.
About the app.UseEndpoints(), I've already had it.
About the logs, I'm not able to reproduce the steps you described. Can you please provide me some screenshots ?

Comment: Try to create virtual directory on Azure Web app level:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0cbdbd8e-2112-4c7b-8871-7a907bf1de37/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-directory-with-azure-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Is it a Linux or Windows OS, how you deploy it?

Comment: It's Linux, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're actually pushing the zip to the app service (which would explain the 404). The AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 task you're using requires a `Package` or `packageForLinux` parameter if you use the webAppLinux type (scroll down a bit from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#prerequisites-for-the-task)), so that it knows what to publish to your app service.

Comment: In the documentation you linked, we can read that for the `Package` variable : "(Required if ConnectionType = PublishProfile or WebAppKind = webApp, apiApp, functionApp, mobileApp, webAppLinux, or functionAppLinux) File path to the package, or to a folder containing App Service contents generated by MSBuild, or to a compressed zip or war file." Also, the package is well unzipped when I browse the server with kudu

Comment: If it's there when you browse with kudu, that blows up my theory. Have you by any chance tried manually zipping & pushing the contents of your local bin/ folder via zipdeploy? That would help eliminate issues with the publish/deploy, and give you more of a like-for-like comparison with what you have locally